# Select pairs with unique elements

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a list of potential matches in this form:

```
rev_id, click_id
A,   1
A,   2
B,   1
B,   2
B,   3
C,   3
```

How can select pairs with unique elements be so that values in both columns show up only once? The result would looks like:

```
rev_id, click_id
A,   1
B,   2
C,   3
```

Is there a window function that would get me what I want?

```
select rev_id, ???? 
from matches
group by 1
```

Comment: Why no `A, 2` instead of `B, 2`?

Comment: C and A seem obvious, but how are you choosing that you want 2 for the B value?  If you don't care and only want once just `SELECT rev_id, MIN(click_id) as click_id FROM matches GROUP BY rev_id`

Comment: This would be valid output as well: `A,   2;  B,   1;  C,   3`.

Comment: @Matt, With `SELECT rev_id, MIN(click_id) as click_id FROM matches GROUP BY rev_id` I will get result:  `A,   1; B,   1; C,   3` but its not valid in my case because 1 shows up twice in the second column.

Comment: now I get your need.  you want only 1 click_id per rev_id but a click_id to only be represented once.  Can that always be the case in your data?

Comment: @matt, yes, thats right. Sorry about the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

so with your requirement in your comment that a you can only use a click_id once it becomes way more difficult.  But because you are using 3 rev_ids you can use 3 Cartesian joins and then narrow down to which options are allowed then choose 1 and format the way you want. Unfortunately this type of answer isn't very scalable.

```
;WITH cteOption AS (
    SELECT TOP 1 *
    FROM
       (
          SELECT DISTINCT
             CASE
                WHEN m1.rev_id < m2.rev_id AND m1.rev_id < m3.rev_id THEN m1.rev_id
                WHEN m2.rev_id < m1.rev_id AND m2.rev_id < m3.rev_id THEN m2.rev_id
                ELSE m3.rev_id
             END as rev1
             ,CASE
                WHEN m1.rev_id < m2.rev_id AND m1.rev_id < m3.rev_id THEN m1.click_id
                WHEN m2.rev_id < m1.rev_id AND m2.rev_id < m3.rev_id THEN m2.click_id
                ELSE m3.click_id
             END as click1
             ,CASE
                WHEN m1.rev_id > m2.rev_id AND m1.rev_id < m3.rev_id THEN m1.rev_id
                WHEN m1.rev_id > m3.rev_id AND m1.rev_id < m2.rev_id THEN m1.rev_id
                WHEN m2.rev_id > m1.rev_id AND m2.rev_id < m3.rev_id THEN m2.rev_id
                WHEN m2.rev_id > m3.rev_id AND m2.rev_id < m1.rev_id THEN m2.rev_id
                ELSE m3.rev_id
             END as rev2
             ,CASE
                WHEN m1.rev_id > m2.rev_id AND m1.rev_id < m3.rev_id THEN m1.click_id
                WHEN m1.rev_id > m3.rev_id AND m1.rev_id < m2.rev_id THEN m1.click_id
                WHEN m2.rev_id > m1.rev_id AND m2.rev_id < m3.rev_id THEN m2.click_id
                WHEN m2.rev_id > m3.rev_id AND m2.rev_id < m1.rev_id THEN m2.click_id
                ELSE m3.click_id
             END as click2
             ,CASE
                WHEN m1.rev_id > m2.rev_id AND m1.rev_id > m3.rev_id THEN m1.rev_id
                WHEN m2.rev_id > m1.rev_id AND m2.rev_id > m3.rev_id THEN m2.rev_id
                ELSE m3.rev_id
             END as rev3
             ,CASE
                WHEN m1.rev_id > m2.rev_id AND m1.rev_id > m3.rev_id THEN m1.click_id
                WHEN m2.rev_id > m1.rev_id AND m2.rev_id > m3.rev_id THEN m2.click_id
                ELSE m3.click_id
             END as click3
          FROM
             @matches m1
             CROSS JOIN @matches m2
             CROSS JOIN @matches m3
          WHERE
             m1.rev_id <> m2.rev_id
             AND m1.rev_id <> m3.rev_id
             AND m2.rev_id <> m3.rev_id
             AND m1.click_id <> m2.click_id
             AND m1.click_id <> m3.click_id
             AND m2.click_id <> m3.click_id
    ) t
)

SELECT
    rev1 as rev_id
    ,click1 as click_id
FROM
    cteOption
UNION ALL
SELECT
    rev2 as rev_id
    ,click2 as click_id
FROM
    cteOption
UNION ALL
SELECT
    rev3 as rev_id
    ,click3 as click_id
FROM
    cteOption
```

I am sure there is a recursion way of doing it as well but I don't know if redshift supports that and don't have the time to chase down just yet.

OLD:

from your comments if you don't care which value but you just want to keep a value per rev_id you could just take the highest or lowest value.

```
SELECT rev_id, MIN(click_id) as click_id FROM matches GROUP BY rev_id
```

OR

```
SELECT rev_id, MAX(click_id) as click_id FROM matches GROUP BY rev_id
```